# Android: правильная локализация приложений

Tags: локализация, android, русификация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто на личном опыте сталкивался, или читал рекомендации по тому, как правильно локализовывать приложения, что бы в переводах и названиях строк не было путаницы?
Я веду одновременно два файла локализации: на английском и русском, и довольно быстро столкнулся с тем, что начал не понимать в какой момент времени вставлять нужную  строку, так как строки начинают плодится с разными названиями и почти одинаковым значением. Например слово "закрыть" используется для как для закрытия диалогового окна, так и для закрытия меню и может ещё где-то будет использоваться. Хранить его лучше как строку

```
<string name="close">закрыть</string>
```

или разделять на соответствующие элементы интерфейса?

```
<string name="alert_dialog_button_close">закрыть</string>
<string name="nawigation_drawer_close">закрыть</string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я применяю смешанную схему:

```
<!-- common resources -->
<string name="close">закрыть</string>

<!-- MyActivity resources-->
<string name="editName">Редактировать имя</string>
```

Для того, чтобы убедиться, что строки в разных ресурсах все в наличии, время от времени провожу diff - тогда видно в каком ресурсе упущена строка

Comment: > Для того, чтобы убедиться, что строки в разных ресурсах все в наличии, время от времени провожу diff - тогда видно в каком ресурсе упущена строка

Вы имеете в виду проверку, все ли строки присутствуют во всех локализациях? Так это и `lint` умеет, причём достаточно давно.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ @falstaf - а можно про это поподробнее, что за ПО для проверки?

Comment: @ua6xh, это утилита из `Android SDK` (SDK/tools/lint). В Eclipse (при наличии установленного ADT Plugin) и в IDEA (`Analyze` -> `Inspect code`) имеется интеграция с ним, что позволяет все ошибки `lint`'а видеть сразу в IDE. Помимо этого, у `lint`'а имеется ещё множество других полезных инспекций (drawables, parent overdraws, strings, etc). В общем, рекомендую начать использовать.

Comment: @falstaf - Спасибо большое! Сейчас буду разбираться с ним)

Comment: @falstaf С недавних пор вижу во время пересборки проекта предупреждения об отсутствии локализации, видимо это lint выкидывает. В любом случае спасибо за наводку. Для @ua6xh касаемо diff: выбираем в IDEA два ресурсных файла и говорим compare files и все.

Answer (score 1):

Второй подход (разделять на соответствующие элементы интерфейса) мне показался удобнее и гибче, его и применяю.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день! Если Вы заинтересованы в локализации web-ПО, ПО для персональных компьютеров, ПО для мобильных устройств либо иного вида программного обеспечения, я рекомендую Вам использовать этот инструмент на базе web: https://poeditor.com/ POEditor является интуитивным, хорошо проработанным инструментом, обладающим рядом полезных свойств, которые помогают организовать процесс управления переводом. Он поддерживает множество популярных форматов файлов и обладает собственным API, что обеспечивает лучшую автоматизацию. Желаю Вам больших успехов в Ваших проектах!